# How to parse a string into an array

Tags: javascript

If a have a string in this format:

```
$parsethis = 'string[1][2]';
```

How do I parse it so my result is an array like:

```
$parsed = ['string', 1 , 2]
```

Comment: Your expected output is invalid. Objects have key/value pairs. Did you want an array instead? `['string', 1, 2]`?

Comment: There is no strong typing in JavaScript. The type of an array's items is always object. Or, `object[]` for example in c#. You can still individually get item's types though, but the array declaration itself has no strong type.

Comment: Are you sure you tagged the right language?

Comment: sorry guys corrected my output. Yes I am looking for an array since I thought there might be a way to use the split() function.

Comment: Well, the title is quite confusing. Improved the English a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think REGEX is the way to go here, in compiination with the Arrays split method.

```
var array = $parsed.split(/\]\[|\[|\]/);

console.log(array) results in
Array [ "string", "1", "2", "" ]
```

iam not very good at using regular expressions, but maybe this is leading you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var $parsethis = 'string[1][2]';
var arr = $parsethis.replace(/\]/g,'').split('['); 
//arr = ["string", "1", "2"]
alert(arr); //alerts "string,1,2"
```

The `arr` array will be all strings, though. Based on the question, I do not know how you will be using the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array from that string using str.split(), and then cleaning it up with str.replace().

```
var parsed = parsethis.split('['); 
console.log(parsed); // ["string", "1]", "2]"]
for(var i = 0; i++; i<parsed.length){
  parsed[i] = parsed[i].replace(']','');
}
console.log(parsed); // ["string", "1", "2"]
```